Implementing Hybrid Filtered Beam Search in NetworkX
I'm trying to implement a Hybrid Filtered Beam Search algorithm using NetworkX to find the optimal path in a directed graph. The goal is to calculate the state transitions and use beam search to find the optimal trajectory (sigma). However, I'm encountering several issues, such as infinite loops and type errors during the execution.
Inputs:

E: Trajectory or the tour.
C: Cost matrix (a computed distance matrix of the graph).
Beta_g: The global filter (usually applied when there are no
successors of the parent node).
Beta_l: The local filter (applied after sorting the sublist by g+h).


I'm relatively new to working with graphs and would appreciate any help. Specifically, I would be grateful for:

Suggestions on how to resolve infinite loops and type errors in my
current implementation.
A list of exercises to practice graph problems, starting from
beginner to advanced levels.
Example code or references to similar implementations to help me
understand the concepts better.

